# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Couldn't find com.google.a.a.c.a

Tags: java, android, exception, fatal-error

I am getting this `Exception` repeatedly in ***CrashListics***  from Samsung devices with operating system `5.0.1` i searched in SO a lot and find that it is a bug in samsung devices but unable to find any solution. can anyone suggest me how to handle this exception (any solution or any trick) ?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Couldn't find
>   com.google.a.a.c.a
>          at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:659)
>          at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
>          at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:170)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:242)
>          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.excludeField(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.excludeField(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.excludeField(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.excludeField(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(Unknown Source)
>          at **com.app.Data.Sessions.LoginSession.createLoginSession(Unknown
>   Source)**
>          at com.app.Data.UserInformation.getInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.app.Main.LocationUpdateService.locationUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.app.Main.LocationUpdateService.locationUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at com.app.Main.LocationUpdateService$1.onLocationChanged(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
>          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
>          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

In `createLoginSession` what i am doing is :

```
public void createLoginSession(UserData userData) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String info = gson.toJson(userData);
    editor.putString(INFO, info);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Do you use proguard in your gradle?

Comment: @RoShanShan yes i am using

Answer (score 3):

YOu need to keep your model `UserData`, don't obfuscate that.  Like this:

`-keep class yourpackage.model.** { *; }`

and keep your gson

`-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }`

Comment: @KapilRajput Did it help?
If yes, please mark as answer